# Carousel child bug when containing items div (nested carousel)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I meet an issue when using nested carousel, it happens when i add `item` divs in the child carousel:

```
<div id="carousel-parent" class="carousel slide">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="active item">
      <div id="carousel-child" class="carousel slide">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="active item">ITEM_1</div>
          <div class="item">ITEM_2</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">…</div>
    <div class="item">…</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here, if i delete the "ITEM_1" and "ITEM_2" `divs` (child `carousel-inner` empty), everything works great. 
But if i add just one `item div` on the child carousel, when i call the `next` and `prev` parent's carousel javascript methods, i get some really weird behaviors (apprently, the `active` class is not able to update its position itself in the scenario).

Is it normal ? How to avoid that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested carousel is not supported because "Would be a bad experience all around"
[Github issue](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/4359)